# Binder cannot bind Context.SIP_SERVICE - SIP Client not working on Nougat

Tags: android, sip, voip

I've implemented SIP feature in my app. I am currently working on Galaxy Tab SM-T580 with Nougat. Problem started at the moment when I've decided to upgrade Android (from 6.0 to mentioned 7.0) - then my SIP client stopped working.

When I try to open my sipManager implementation with `open(sipProfile, pi, null)` method

```
android.net.sip.SipException: SipService is dead and is restarting...
    at android.net.sip.SipManager.checkSipServiceConnection(SipManager.java:183)
```

is thrown.

Debugging code I can see that SipManager from android.net.sip doesn't bind Context.SIP_SERVICE service (SipManager:175). Code and configs I am using are copy paste from Android Docs - [Android Sip Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip)